# Android Pin It SDK - How to share local image?

Tags: android, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

I am trying to use  [Pinterest SDK](http://developers.pinterest.com/android/) . I have tried codes given in that link , its working fine for  me. I need to share image  from SD card. How to do it ?

I have tried with following code,

```
 pinIt = new PinItButton(this);
 pinIt.setImageUri(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/EREADER/97890352465398/OEBPS/Cover.jpg"));
pinIt.setDescription("A place kitten!");
RelativeLayout _relLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutRelative);
pinIt.setDescription("A place kitten!");
_relLayout.addView(pinIt);
```

it gives me error like

> imageUrl and/or imageUri cannot be null! Did you call setImageUrl(String) or setImageUri(Uri)?

Comment: a better practice is not to use hard coded SD card path. BTW, are you sure the image is put under `sdcard/EREADER/97890352465398/OEBPS/Cover.jpg` ? Please do check the file exists or not in your code before you assign it.

Comment: just for the testing purpose it is hard coded. File is there in the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

try this `Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/EREADER/97890352465398/OEBPS/Cover.jpg"));`